# Flutter Youtube Native Player on iOS plays after routed back

Tags: flutter, youtube, native, video-player

I would like to use this plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_native_player) because it has minimal buttons, but if I push the back button it continuous playing in background. I can go back but the video starting again with the previous sound's in background etc.
I do not know how to reach it's controller. Can I get some help?

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uhu/common/widgets/base_stateless_widget.dart';
import 'package:youtube_native_player/android/constrant.dart';
import 'package:youtube_native_player/android/video_player_controller.dart';
import 'package:youtube_native_player/youtube_native_player.dart';

class YoutubeIosWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  YoutubeIosWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<YoutubeIosWidget> {
  String position = "Get Current Position";
  String status = "Get Player Status";
  String videoDuration = "Get Video Duration";
  String _source = CommonThings.videoId;
  bool isMute = false;

  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // This pauses video while navigating to next page.
//   super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CommonThings.videoId = "";
    return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {});
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          YoutubeNativePlayer(
              context: context,
              source: _source,
              quality: YoutubeQuality.HD,
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              autoPlay: true,
              loop: false,
              reactToOrientationChange: true,
              startFullScreen: true,
              controlsActiveBackgroundOverlay: false,
              controlsTimeOut: Duration(seconds: 1),
              playerMode: YoutubePlayerMode.DEFAULT,
              switchFullScreenOnLongPress: true,
              callbackController: (controller) {
                _controller = controller;
              },
              onError: (error) {
                print(error);
              },
              onVideoEnded: () => Navigator.pop(context))
        ],
      ),
    ));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment your dispose code and also close (or dispose) your video controller:

```
void dispose() {
  // This pauses video while navigating to next page.
  super.dispose();
  _controller.close(); // or _controller.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought and tried this but not working...
I stepped forward and wrote this the plugins' YoutubeNativePlayerIOS dart file, where it was missing...
And it works now.

So it is needed in the plugin's ios file.
Thanks again